# Loading large data file, fast replot

Tags: gnuplot, large-data

I work with large data files (~300 Mb) to visualize scientific data. Well, when I have one script, waiting 10 secs for output is not big problem, but if I want to experiment with other techniques it starts to be a problem. Is there any way to preload this 300 Mb file into memory in gnuplot to get fast replots? I tried to load datafile into /dev/shm, but it makes no difference.

Comment: No, you cannot preload a data set. You could try using `every` to decimate your data while experimenting with the options, something like `every 10` to plot every 10th point. Or, if its about selecting a view in 3D, you can hold the `Ctrl`-key while rotating. The replot is done only when you release the key.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe do you know some other plotting programs when I can do same trick?